# Make jQuery code simpler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to make my code more streamlined so it's not so heavy.

```js
 var t;
 $(".sn-fresh").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".um-cat").hide();
   clearTimeout(t);
   $("#ultra-menu, #um-fresh").fadeIn(600);
 });

 $(".sn-salt").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".um-cat").hide();
   clearTimeout(t);
   $("#ultra-menu, #um-salt").fadeIn(600);
 });

 $(".sn-shoot").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".um-cat").hide();
   clearTimeout(t);
   $("#ultra-menu, #um-shoot").fadeIn(600);
 });

 $(".sn-eques").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".um-cat").hide();
   clearTimeout(t);
   $("#ultra-menu, #um-eques").fadeIn(600);
 });

 $(".sn-cloth").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".um-cat").hide();
   clearTimeout(t);
   $("#ultra-menu, #um-cloth").fadeIn(600);
 });

 $(".sn-brand").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".um-cat").hide();
   clearTimeout(t);
   $("#ultra-menu, #um-brand").fadeIn(600);
 });

 $("#ultra-menu").mouseleave(function() {
   clearTimeout(t);
   t = setTimeout(function() {
     $("#ultra-menu, .um-cat").fadeOut(600);
   }, 300);
 });
 $("#main-navigation a").mouseleave(function() {
   clearTimeout(t);
   t = setTimeout(function() {
     $("#ultra-menu, .um-cat").fadeOut(600);
   }, 300);
 });
 $("#ultra-menu").mouseenter(function() {
   clearTimeout(t);
   $("#ultra-menu").fadeIn(600);
 });
```

Comment: Do you have your HTML as well?

Comment: I actually don't see much wrong with this. It's a lot of code, but it seems succinct to me.

Comment: @QuinnRoundy Yeah it was really just to bring it down abit MTO produced a great idea.

Comment: Just another question about use javascript for css-tasks. I am very sad.

Comment: @PeterRader Explain what makes you think this jquery could have a CSS counterpart. This question is about simplifying Jquery code. and nothing that the Jquery is doing can be achieved with CSS otherwise I would have done so.

Comment: @DCdaz Using css-transitions you can replace everything of the javascript if the html-structure is right, even the Timeout-work. Please dont think i am cruel by my comment: if you had html, i would give a complete answer.

Comment: @PeterRader You cant. You would see what I mean if you could see the HTML but basicly #ultra-menu is far away from the activator links for any hover also because of it's nature I cant just add class to cause a transition to it either. Otherwise I honestly would have.

Comment: @DCdaz yes, usually you trigger event by switch css-classes, but you can use other markers like data-attributes. And hey, `.hide()` changes the html anyway. I think you are working on a plugin, so you can not foresee what html the plugin will work on.

Comment: @PeterRader yeah the to much of it is variable and dynamic so there is no real way for me to target it properly I know there is data attributes but  they themselves could be bent especially if they are being overridden elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make it more DRY by eliminating the repeated code:

```
var names = ["fresh","salt","shoot","eques","cloth","brand"];

names.forEach( function( name ){
  $(".sn-"+name).mouseenter(function() {
    $(".um-cat").hide();
    clearTimeout(t);
    $("#ultra-menu, #um-" + name ).fadeIn(600);
  });
});
```

and either:

```
$("#ultra-menu, #main-navigation a").mouseleave(function() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ultra-menu, .um-cat").fadeOut(600);
  }, 300);
});
```

or:

```
var menus = [ "#ultra-menu", "#main-navigation a" ];

menus.forEach( function( menu ){
  $(menu).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#ultra-menu, .um-cat").fadeOut(600);
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually he should add a common class to his elements and add the listener only on this class. He can then detect the kind of element it is with a `data-name` attribute or something.

Comment: @Johnride That can't happen unfortunately.

Comment: @DCdaz why? Unless you have no control on the HTML there is no reason you can't add a class and an attribute to your elements.

Comment: You answered that yourself there. There is a couple of reasons why the class should not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

```
$(".sn-fresh").mouseenter(yourfunction(e);
function yourfunction(){
$('.um-cat').hide();
clearTimeout(t);
$('#ultra-menu', #'+e.target.id).fadeIn(600); 
}
```

With this method it will dynamically do the fade in with the target parent's name.

Comment: It's not an ID though. its a class that is different from the ID